# Get AJAX to fill Datatables with JSON data sent from flask and separately render the html

Tags: json, ajax, flask

It now all works. If you want to load a file containing the JSON payload uncomment this line

`// "url": "static/objects2.txt", // This works for a static file`

and comment this one,

`"url": "/index_get_data", // This now also works`

flaskTest.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/index_get_data')
def stuff():
  # Assume data comes from somewhere else
  data = {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John Q Public",
        "position": "System Architect",
        "salary": "$320,800",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office": "Edinburgh",
        "extn": "5421"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Larry Bird",
        "position": "Accountant",
        "salary": "$170,750",
        "start_date": "2011/07/25",
        "office": "Tokyo",
        "extn": "8422"
      }]
  }
  return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

/templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Datatables Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Heading</h1>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<script>


function setupData() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                // "url": "static/objects2.txt", // This works for a static file
                "url": "/index_get_data", // This now also works
                "dataType": "json",
                "dataSrc": "data",
                "contentType":"application/json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "position"},
                {"data": "office"},
                {"data": "extn"},
                {"data": "start_date"},
                {"data": "salary"}
            ]
        });
    });
}

$( window ).on( "load", setupData );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe doing `json.dumps()` for the data.

Comment: @Divise I tried it, same result. I suspect that ajax is expecting more than just a json object.  Thank you for your effort!

Comment: If you're just trying to specifically receive json data from the request you do not have to do `return render_template()` you can just do `return jsonify(mydata)`

Comment: Divise you put me on the right track.   @kthorngren of the DataTables forum summed it up as "The problem is you can't return the web page and data at the same time for Datatables. You will need to return the web page, it will load and Datatables will initialize then send the ajax request. This will need to be a different URL that will simply return the JSON data. You will have two Python functions; index and dt_index (or whatever you want to call the URL for the ajax request)."  I'm going to edit the question to show the solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem I'll add it as an answer for others to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing `return render_template()` just do:

`return jsonfiy(my data)`

You're sending data not a view so there is no need to return a template render as a response.

Comment: Hi, did something changed in Datatable? I am trying your code and get this error : Invalid JSON response